# How do I do unbuffered substitution in a perl oneliner?

Tags: perl

I've got a bash script that wraps mvn (Apache Maven) to add colour to its output. A cut-down version of what it does is:

```
mvn "$@" | sed -e "s/^\[INFO\] \-.*/$bldblu&$rst/g"
```

where `$bldblu` is the ANSI color escape characters for bold blue, and `$rst` resets the colours.

The issue I'm having is that sometimes mvn writes a line that doesn't end in a newline, thus (as far as I can tell) sed keeps waiting for input and never prints the prompt (which makes it seem like Maven is hanging). I've tried adding `-u` to sed but that just forces sed to do line-by-line buffering instead of buffering more than one line - not helpful for me.

So far this is what I've come up with:

```
mvn "$@" | perl -pe "$| = 1; s/^(\[INFO\] \-.*)/$bldblu\$1$rst/g"
```

but I think the use of `-p` is not correct here. Any help?

Comment: What specific problem are you seeing ?

Comment: It doesn't print the last line from mvn because it doesn't terminate with a line feed/carriage return

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem either, but what about trying the /gs or /gsm or /gm modifiers (instead of /g)?

Comment: @knb, please see the updated question - using /s and /m (as far as I understand) would make it worst.

Comment: @dale-wijnand what about `s/^(\[INFO\] \-.*)\Z/$bldblu\$1$rst/g` ? - Note the \Z (select to end of string)

Comment: Nope.. Seems like the problem is with unbuffered reading as well..

Answer (score 0):

A substitution may be overkill, especially when the replacement pattern has special characters in it. How about this?

```
export bldblu
export rst
mvn "$@" | perl -pe 'if(/^.INFO. -/){ $_=$ENV{bldblu}.$_.$ENV{rst} }'
```

or rather than reinventing the wheel

```
mvn "$@" | perl -MTerm::ANSIColor -pe 
    '$_=color("bold blue").$_.color("reset") if /^.INFO. -/'
```

Comment: That successfully colours the line, however it doesn't resolve the issue with the buffering. As far as I can tell the issue is `-p` wraps the program with `while (<>) { ... }` and `while (<>)` processes for each line, so a line which doesn't terminate isn't processed until it is.. unfortunately.

Comment: How is there an issue with buffering, unless the `mvn` program is starved for input? You oughta be able to fix that with a simple `mvn "$@" </dev/null | perl ...`

Comment: Yes, in my use-case it sometimes prompts for input, that's the problem.

Comment: @DaleWijnand: it is only a problem if the prompt expect the answer on the same line. If it is not unnaceptable for your use case: have it prompt with a terminating newline? (ie, the answer is on the next line)

Answer (score 0):

#### (workaround) Use sed --unbuffered

I couldn't figure out the solution but thankfully this is good enough for my particular usage:

```
cat - | sed --unbuffered 's/.*?from//g'
```

But I too would like to know the answer. Perl one line substitution is a key idiom in my toolbelt.

#### BSD

Looks like there is no common flag for GNU and BSD. For the latter, you'd need:

```
     -l      Make output line buffered.
```